# jQuery Load function doesn't load the URL result?

Tags: jquery

I have the generated link to the ISSUU's PDF:

http://issuu.com/press/docs/2008-12?mode=window&printButtonEnabled=false&shareButtonEnabled=false&searchButtonEnabled=false&backgroundColor=%23222222

then, I want to load that URL content into a DIV:

```
$("#inner").load('http://issuu.com/press/docs/2008-12?mode=window&printButtonEnabled=false&shareButtonEnabled=false&searchButtonEnabled=false&backgroundColor=%23222222');
```

the server returns 200 status (OK) but, the FireBug marks that request red:

[image]

and nothing shows inside that DIV. Why ?

### Edit

It also fails if I change the request to Post:

```
$.post('http://issuu.com/press/docs/2008-12?mode=window&printButtonEnabled=false&shareButtonEnabled=false&searchButtonEnabled=false&backgroundColor=%23222222',{},
                function(res){ $("#inner").html(res);});
```

Comment: Different domain? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers won't allow cross-domain AJAX calls.

You could use an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

To circumvent the same origin policy you could you use a proxy script on the same domain to fetch the remote page.